# ruby on rails : <top (required)>': superclass must be a Class (Symbol given) (TypeError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In my rails server, this error occurs when I enter 'rails console production' and I don't know why.
What I'm trying to do is generate user information and save it in my database.
I guess there is some json or symbol error, but I cannot solve...
Any help will be appreciated.

Here's my error message.

```
user_controller.rb:17:in `<top (required)>': superclass must be a Class (Symbol given) (TypeError)
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:360:in `require_or_load'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:317:in `depend_on'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:233:in `require_dependency'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:472:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:471:in `each'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:471:in `block in eager_load!'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:469:in `each'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:469:in `eager_load!'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:346:in `eager_load!'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `each'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.5/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.5/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.5/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:429:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.5/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.5/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.5/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.5/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.5/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.5/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:203:in `tsort_each'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
from /home/ec2-user/popcake/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require_environment!'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:142:in `require_application_and_environment!'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:67:in `console'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/app_rails_loader.rb:45:in `require'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/app_rails_loader.rb:45:in `block in exec_app_rails'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/app_rails_loader.rb:34:in `loop'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/app_rails_loader.rb:34:in `exec_app_rails'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/cli.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/railties-4.2.5/bin/rails:9:in `require'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/railties-4.2.5/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/bin/rails:23:in `load'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/bin/rails:23:in `<main>'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

and this is my user_controller

```
require 'openssl'
require 'jwt'
require 'json'

class UserController < 
    def register_native
        userparams=params.require(:user).permit(:uuid, :username, :email, :encrypted_password)
        expire = Time.now.to_i + 4 * 3600
        rsa_private = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.generate 2048
        rsa_public = rsa_private.public_key
        token = JWT.encode userparams, rsa_private, 'RS256'
        jsonparams ={:uuid => userparams[:uuid],:username => userparams[:username],:email => userparams[:email],:encrypted_password => userparams[:encrypted_password],:private_key =>rsa_private,:token =>token, :exp => expire}.to_json
        responses={:public_key=>rsa_public, :token=>token}.to_json
        User.create(jsonparams)
        render json: responses
    end
```

Comment: `class UserController < ApplicationController`

Comment: Why the off topic votes? This is a perfect question for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 7):

Try this

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
```

Why does your code not work?

```
# bad code
class UserController < 
  def register_native
  end
end
```

Everything in Ruby is a statement,

- `class` is a statement with three arguments: class name, superclass object, and body
- `def` is a statement that creates a method and returns the name as a symbol

Your code is thus missing a superclass argument and hence the first method definition is instead executes and its return value used as superclass argument.

In pseudo code this looks like

```
# pseudocode 
define_class(
  "UserController", 
  define_method("register_native", &empty_block),
  &empty_block
)
```

So what happens?

- `def` creates a method in the global scope and returns the symbol `:register_native`
- This symbol is then passed to the `class` statement as superclass argument
- Which raises the error `"superclass must be a Class (Symbol given)"`

Fun fact, any statement that returns a class is valid for the superclass expressions

```
# Fun fact, this is valid Ruby
class Surprise < [String, Array, Fixnum, Hash].sample
end
```

Comment: Thank you...! I missed the most basic one!

Answer (score 1):

In your `user_controller.rb` file change:

```
class UserController <
```

to

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
```

This error is occurring because Your `class` is not inheriting from the `superclass`.